# Prevent redirect after submitting the form

Tags: 7, forms

In Drupal 7 profile2 module, want to make profile2 edit form to stay on the form itself
after clicking SAVE button.

With the following code, it stays on the form itself and displays the values correctly.
But it does not save actually. When coming back to the form, it still shows the previous 
values there.

So the following code makes the submitting to stay on the form itself but does not save
the result into database.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'profile2_edit_main_form'){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] ='custom_profile2_edit_submit';
  }
}

function custom_profile2_edit_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
  unset($_GET['destination']);
  unset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination']);
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['redirect'] = REDIRECT_URL;
  drupal_set_message('Changes were saved');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved to make the desired redirection like this:

```
function redirect_to_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "page_article_node_form") {
        //$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_redirect_to_edit';
        $form['#action'] = '?destination=node/' . $form['nid']['#value'] . '/edit';
    }
}
```

Reference: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1074616#comment-5115792